# IP traffic use cases, which could be broken by egress filtering

Tags: ip

Egress filtering (blocking potentially spoofed IP packets with source IP outside the sub-network) is breaking multihoming.

However, what are other "normal", residential IP connection use cases which the egress filtering would break? That is, when would a home Internet user expect to be able to send traffic with source IPs, which is not their own, given that they have their own public IPv4 address?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Generally, it's a matter of Usability vs. Security.

Comment: I'm just curious about specific applications, which actually NEED to send IP packets with "foreign" source IP addresses in order to function. Like Tor or some types of VPN.

Comment: The filter will block them, of course.

Comment: @Konstantin, I think you misunderstand how Tor and VPN work. Both actually use your real source IP address to send traffic to the Internet. In the case of VPN, it is to your VPN end point (your actual traffic is tunneled inside the VPN connection so it appears to originate from the VPN end point). With Tor, the first relay can see your real source IP address (but doesn't know if you are a source or relay), but not the destination. It is only the final relay that sees the destination (but doesn't see the source). Neither one sends packets with "foreign" source IP addresses to the Internet.

Comment: @YLearn Thanks for your comment! That was my understanding as well. I was just led to believe that egress filtering is not widely used because it would be breaking some applications of the IP protocol. However, multihoming was the only application I could find that could potentially be broken by egress filtering by ISPs. I just don't understand why we still have spoofed IP address attacks in the wild.